# php ImageCreate

Tags: php

I am new to php and am trying to simply print a message and create a rectangle but this doesn't work. I have looked at the gd extension in the php.ini file in the wamp directory and it is not commented out. Please help - why won't it work :(

```
<?php
print ("hello world");
$im = ImageCreate(200,200);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
ImageFilledRectangle($im,50,50,150,150,$black);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
ImagePNG($im);
?>
```

Comment: Error messages? `doesn't work` is not an error...

Comment: there is no error message, the only thing that appears is the "broken link" icon you get when an image in not linked to correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the string `hello world`, and then outputting the image. This will result in corrupted image data, because it will have 11 bytes at the start of it that make no sense in the context of an image.

Remove the `print('hello world');` line, and it should output a valid image - But your page will not contain the text `hello world`, you'll need to output a proper HTML page with the text on and point the `src` attribute of an `img` tag to the PHP script that generates the image if you want that to work.

For example:

page.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    hello world<br>
    <img src="image.php" />
  </body>
</html>
```

image.php

```
<?php

$im = ImageCreate(200,200);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
ImageFilledRectangle($im,50,50,150,150,$black);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
ImagePNG($im);

?>
```

Comment: Right, now I understand, thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have an `print ("hello world");` at the beginning of the code. If you are to call `header()`, there **must not** be *ANY* output before the output you want. Remove that line, and your code will work. Please always read the [related documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: And more importantly: Enable error-reporting and always check your [logs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) for errors and warnings - they are there for a reason.